# pandas DataFrame: get cells in column that are NaN, None, empty string/list, etc

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

there seems to be different methods to check if a cell is not set (NaN, by checking `isnull`) or whether it contains an empty string or list, but what is the most pythonic way to retrieve all cells that are NaN, None, empty string/list, etc. at the same time?

So far I got:

```
df = df[df['colname'].isnull() or df['colname'] == None or len(df['colname']) == 0]
```

Cheers!

Comment: have a look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html and here:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html

Answer (score 3):

One idea is chain [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with compare lengths by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'a':[None,np.nan,[],'','aa', 0],
})

m = df['a'].isna() | df['a'].str.len().eq(0)
print (m)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Comment: May I ask why did you use `df['a'].str.len().eq(0)` instead of, for example, `df['a'].str.len() == 0`?

Comment: @pedjjj - It is solution with less `()`, but be free use `(df['a'].str.len() == 0)`

Comment: The code isn't fully bullet proof, yet. I ran into this one using the code from your snippet. `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!` Do you know how to fix this? I already tried using `astype(str)` but this didn't help: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'task_id_ps1_single_allsides_random'`

Comment: @pedjjj do you try `m = df['a'].isna() | df['a'].astype(str).str.len().eq(0)` and fail?